# post data through httpwebrequest and get it in php

Tags: c#, php, httpwebrequest

I have this php code in server :

```
foreach($_POST as $pdata)
echo " *-* ".  $pdata." *-*<br> ";
```

and i am sending post data by httpwebrequest in c# :

```
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/22") as HttpWebRequest;
        //Specifing the Method
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        //Data to Post to the Page, itis key value pairs; separated by "&"
        string data = "Username=username&password=password";
        //Setting the content type, it is required, otherwise it will not work.
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //Getting the request stream and writing the post data
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            sw.Write(data);
        }
        //Getting the Respose and reading the result.
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

static html codes of php page are shown.
but nothing of posted value are shown in messagebox .that means no data are posted.
what is wrong?

Comment: Your PHP code looks good. No idea about c#.

Comment: I guess it's because you didn't specify any content length of the request body.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the bytes of the data.

Try this code, from [this guy's blog post](http://blog.brezovsky.net/).

```
 public string Post(string url, string data) {


           string vystup = null;
           try
           {
               //Our postvars
               byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
               //Initialisation, we use localhost, change if appliable
               HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
               //Our method is post, otherwise the buffer (postvars) would be useless
               WebReq.Method = "POST";
               //We use form contentType, for the postvars.
               WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
               //The length of the buffer (postvars) is used as contentlength.
               WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
               //We open a stream for writing the postvars
               Stream PostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
               //Now we write, and afterwards, we close. Closing is always important!
               PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
               PostData.Close();
               //Get the response handle, we have no true response yet!
               HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
               //Let's show some information about the response
               Console.WriteLine(WebResp.StatusCode);
               Console.WriteLine(WebResp.Server);

               //Now, we read the response (the string), and output it.
               Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
               StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
               vystup =  _Answer.ReadToEnd();

               //Congratulations, you just requested your first POST page, you
               //can now start logging into most login forms, with your application
               //Or other examples.
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }
           return vystup.Trim()+"\n";

        }
```